# Differenze tra "pacco" e "pacchetto"

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, difference

Nel racconto *Fino a che dura il Sole* di Italo Calvino ho letto:

> Invece ogni volta la gran preoccupazione è non perdere di vista *i pacchi
>   e i pacchetti* del trasloco, e i bambini che piangono, e la figliola che le si infiammano
>   gli occhi, e il genero che gli si fonde la dentiera...

Questa frase ha subito attirato la mia attenzione perché io sempre avevo pensato che "i pacchi" e "i pacchetti" fossero la stessa cosa. Immagino che il problema provenga del fatto che nella mia lingua esiste un'unica parola per esprimere questi concetti: "paquet" in catalano o "paquete" in castigliano. Ho appreso dai dizionari che "un pacchetto" è un "piccolo pacco", ma la mia domanda è: esiste qualche differenza di uso o di significato tra questi due vocaboli oltre alle dimensioni fisiche? Fino a che punto deve essere piccolo un pacco per poter essere chiamato "pacchetto"?

Answer (score 7):

Nel caso specifico, l'autore vuole sottolineare la confusione dovuta al trasloco: ci sono pacchi di varie dimensioni, grandi e piccoli, e potrebbero sfuggire quelli piccoli.

Quale sia il confine tra pacco e pacchetto non è determinabile. Il *pacchetto* che porgo come regalo potrebbe essere più grande di un *pacco* che spedisco per posta. Un *pacchetto da regalo* è probabilmente più gradito del *pacco regalo* aziendale, indipendentemente dalle dimensioni, perché dimostra affetto.

Comment: Grazie mille della risposta, @egreg! Immagino che quelli che hai scritto siano esempi di uso di queste due parole. Comunque, a me è difficile apprezzare la differenza. Se si parla di regali, possiamo dire che il vocabolo "pacchetto" ha la connotazione di qualcosa di più personalizzata?

Comment: @Charo Sì, sicuramente *pacchetto* può avere una connotazione più “personale”: il suffisso va bene anche per il vezzeggiativo.

Answer (score 2):

Non ci sono particolari dimensioni specifiche che indichino la differenza tra pacco e pacchetto. Solitamente pacchetto viene utilizzato sia per indicare piccoli pacchi che più specificamente per indicare pacchetti regalo o doni. Inoltre, piccola curiosità, pacco può essere utilizzato come modo per dire fregatura (ad esempio, mi ha venduto questa cosa ma non funziona, mi ha tirato un pacco).

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE e grazie della risposta! Non capisco molto bene la seconda frase: vuoi dire che il vocabolo "pacchetto" si usa solitamente nell'espressione "pacchetti regali"?

Answer (score 2):

Un pacco mi fa pensare a qualcosa di generico. Una scatola, un involucro contenente qualcosa.

Un pacchetto può essere semplicemente un pacco più piccolo (come mi sembra nell’esempio fatto) oppure un regalo.
Può essere anche l’involucro del regalo, in un negozio dopo aver fatto un acquisto (soprattutto in questo periodo natalizio) si può chiedere: Mi fa un pacchetto? – è sottinteso: pacchetto regalo.

Spesso il pacchetto è legato a qualcosa fatto con cura e che si vuole donare. Perché se per esempio devo spedire qualcosa per posta tenderò a definirlo pacco indipendentemente dalla dimensione.

Potrebbe pacchetto corrispondere in spagnolo a "cajetilla"?
Come nel caso:
"pacchetto di sigarette", "cajetilla de cigarrillos".

Comment: "Pacchetto", ma anche "pacco", corrisponde allo spagnolo "paquete". Il vocabolo "cajetilla" si usa esclusivamente per le sigarette ("una cajetilla de cigarrillos"), ma dalle mie parti si dice semplicemente "un paquete de cigarrillos": non saprei dirti dove si usa "cajetilla" invece di "paquete".